# logstash.conf file error -- no discernable error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

Here is the file itself:

```
input {
        file {
                path => ["~/Downloads/log20170629.csv"]
                start_position=> "beginning"
        }
}

filter {
        csv {
                separator=>","
                columns=>["ip","date","time","zone",”cik”,”accession”,”doc”,”code”,”filesize”,”idx”,”norefer”,”noagent”,”find”,”crawler”,”browser"]
        }
}

output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "localhost:9200"
                index => "sec_data"
        }
        stdout{
        }
}
```

I am unsure of the issue. I have double checkd all the curly braces and everything else seems in order?

Comment: Describe what happens and shouldn't or doesn't happen and should. Also provide some data examples so we have something to check your configuration against. Details, details, details!

Comment: Hi, look at the difference between the quotes on "zone" (normal quotes) and ”cik” (stylished quotes) : "zone",”cik”. It might be your issue here.